# Remove HTML Tags MondoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am creating a query to extract description of customers in mongodb. Unfortunately, the description is in HTML Format. Is there a way to replace all HTML tags and make it as " ". Either replace it with " " or remove HTML Tags.

Below is a sample document

```
{ 
        "_id" : ObjectId("61f72aefdc85500a8baa6bb8")
        "CustomerPin" : "22010871", 
        "CustomerName" : "TestLastName, TestFirstName", 
        "Age" : 39.0, 
        "Gender" : "Male", 
        "Description" : "<p><span>This will be a test description</span><br/></p>", 
}
```

The output should remove  "p", "span", and "br". Is there a function in mongodb to remove them all at once without repeating $project

This is the expected output:

```
{ 
        "_id" : ObjectId("61f72aefdc85500a8baa6bb8")
        "CustomerPin" : "22010871", 
        "CustomerName" : "TestLastName, TestFirstName", 
        "Age" : 39.0, 
        "Gender" : "Male", 
        "Description" : "This will be a test description", 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a regex to match HTML tags. `<(?:"[^"]*"['"]*|'[^']*'['"]*|[^'">])+>`. You can write aggregate query to remove HTML tags with this regex and write output to the new collection.

Comment: How can I apply it in $project stage? Im using Mongodb version 4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Mongo 4.2 then you have to find the exact regex which will extract content from HTML. Below you can find an aggregate pipeline and the regex also.

```
db.getCollection("name_of_your_collection").aggregate({
    $set: {
        contentRegex: {
            $regexFind: { input: "$Description", regex: /([^<>]+)(?!([^<]+)?>)/gi }
        }
    }
},
    {
        $set: {
            content: { $ifNull: ["$contentRegex.match", "$Description"] }
        }
    },
    {
        $unset: [ "contentRegex" ]
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this!

I saw some of my data have second paragraph like :

{ 
        "_id" : ObjectId("61f72aefdc85500a8baa6bb8")
        "CustomerPin" : "22010871", 
        "CustomerName" : "TestLastName, TestFirstName", 
        "Age" : 39.0, 
        "Gender" : "Male", 
        "Description" : "<p><span>This will be a test description</span><br/></p><p><span>This will be the second paragraph</span><br/></p>"
}

The query is just getting the first paragraph

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is by removing all tags by regex in pre hook of save method

```
Description.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");
```

See hooks [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre)